# ERROR TypeError: jQuery(...).metismenu is not a function

Tags: jquery, angular, template

Tengo un problema con jQuery en un proyecto de Angular9,me aparece esto en la consola:

> ERROR TypeError: jQuery(...).metismenu is not a function 
>       at NavigationComponent.ngAfterViewInit (navigation.component.ts:16)
>       at callHook (core.js:3937)
>       at callHooks (core.js:3901)
>       at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.js:3842)
>       at refreshView (core.js:11853)
>       at refreshDynamicEmbeddedViews (core.js:13142)
>       at refreshView (core.js:11800)
>       at refreshComponent (core.js:13217)
>       at refreshChildComponents (core.js:11508)
>       at refreshView (core.js:11829)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He revisado en varios foros y no encuentro una solución, tengo exportado el jquery desde assets, pero también lo tengo instalado en mis módulos porque tenia que usar un template.

Comment: prueba  haciendo esto `declare var $: any;` esto va despues de los **imports** y camiba `JQuery('#tuId').metismenu();` por esto `$('#tuId').metismenu();`

Comment: Ya no me marca el error, gracias! pero aun no veo como hacer que no me marque en amarillo el ngAfteViewInit

Comment: Tu componente debe Heredar de AfterView , de esta forma `export class MiComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit  {`

Comment: Te funciono ? si si me avias para publicar una respuesta

Comment: después de un rato vi en un foro que tenia que heredar afterviewinit, y ahora no me sale ningún error pero no funciona jaja, si encuentro la respuesta prometo comentarles algo por aca

Comment: Pero tú pregunta era por los errores

Comment: bueno en resumen si se arreglo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes  declarar un variable global e indicarle a **typescript** el tipado que tiene:

```
Declare var $: any;
```

esto va después de los imports

Ahora debes camibar esto:

```
JQuery('#tuId').metismenu();
```

por esto:

```
$('#tuId').metismenu();
```

Si esta utilizando el ciclo de vida `AfterView` tu componente debe heredar de este, cambia tu componente de la siguiente forma:

```
export class MiComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
```

Comment: Hola amigo, tengo el mismo problema, medice que la función "no es una función" valga la redundancia. y lo peor de todo es que hice todo lo que mencionas y la función la tengo en el index.html. alguna idea? tengo un dia entero en esto y nada que lo he podido solucionar, ya hice npm install jquery --save y nada... revisé el package.json y está bien... sinceramente no entiendo que pasa, tengo el mismo código en stackblitz y ahí si funciona sin problemas, podrías ayudarme ?